# How to author a WiX Burn bundle including a ComPlus proxy installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, com+, burn

We have the scenario with an application with one .Net- and one VB6-client that should be deployed as a single bundle. The VB6 part on its hand contains its binaries as well as an ComPlus proxy. The proxy's installer is generated using COMAdminCatalog.ExportApplication. The three parts is bundled together with WiX Burn and uses the standard bootstrapper application. The creation of the bundle is part of an automatic build and deploy chain.

The problem is how to handle the proxy's installer in the bootstrapper.

- There is no way of controlling the product- and upgrade code or version in COMAdminCatalog.ExportApplication. Thus a previous version can't be upgraded by a new. (At least I have not found a way, is there any?)
- The msi generated from COMAdminCatalog.ExportApplication does not handle repair or reinstall. Will result in error and rollback of whole bundle.
- Two versions of the proxy cannot be installed at the same time. Second one will result in error and rollback.

I have had some progress wrapping the complusproxy.msi in a bat script and use ExePackage instead of MsiPackage. The script begins with removing any previous version of the complusproxy. The problem with this is to get all different install/upgrade/uninstall-scenarios to work correctly.

I'm considering the option to edit the generated complusproxy.msi to get control of the upgrade code and version and add that to the build process.

It feels like I'm trying complex work arounds and it should be a correct, better way of doing it. What would be a better or good enough approach to solve it?